# How can i edit specific row in table using angular5?

Tags: typescript, angular5, edit-tableview

I have a table in my component having multiple records. I want to edit specific row on click edit button in table. But when it is make all rows editable.

I have my table like this

I have a table in which there are multiple rows. When i click on edit button within table so it make all rows of the table editable. Here is my code at stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4hgkz

When i click on edit button so it make all rows editable.

I want only clicked row editable. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is set a property on each row to indicate if it's being edited as shown below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usbhmd

The code for people that do not want to click that.

**Html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Domain</th>
      <th>Registered Date</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let domain of domains; let i = index">
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="!domain.editable">{{domain.name}}</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="domain.name" *ngIf="domain.editable"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="!domain.editable">{{domain.reg_date}}</span>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="domain.reg_date" *ngIf="domain.editable"/>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editDomain(domain)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  domains = [];
  isVisible : boolean = false;
  constructor(){
      this.domains = [
    {
      "_id" : "12323vdfvd234",
      "name" : "sixlogs.com",
      "reg_date" : "2018-04-04",
      "editable": false
    },
    {
      "_id" : "12323vdfvd234",
      "name" : "avanza.com",
      "reg_date" : "2019-04-04",
      "editable": false
    },
    {
      "_id" : "12323vdfvd234",
      "name" : "tps.com",
      "reg_date" : "2018-04-04",
      "editable": false
    },
    {
      "_id" : "12323vdfvd234",
      "name" : "utf.com",
      "reg_date" : "2019-04-04",
      "editable": false
    }
  ]
}

editDomain(domain: any){
    domain.editable = !domain.editable;
  }
}
```

As you can see I have added the `editable` property to the `domains` array, that gets set for the object when the `editDomain` get's triggered by the button click
event. With the `editable` property you can then changed your view to display inputs for each row.

Comment: I don't want to add additional key. So what's the solution then?

Comment: Thanx for help. I have done it without adding any key :)

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: By putting condition `*ngIf="domain._id === editId"`. and on edit i set editId = domain._id

Answer (score 1):

use index of the row

editable attribute in data won't be available generally

https://angular-ivy-dfeleo.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfeleo?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html